# Download a file from ftp subdirectories using cmd script

Tags: cmd, download, ftp, directory, subdirectory

I was trying to download multiple files from our ftp server using the script:

```
mget cd\dir_here\subdir_here\sample*.txt
```

but it didn't work so I tried to change to back slash:

```
mget cd/dir_here/subdir_here/sample*.txt
```

a message

> Type set to A

appeared. What does that mean?

Comment: If you question is really what does "Type set to A" mean, then say it explicitly in question title.

Comment: I took it that she needs general help, and also is confused by the Type Set to A because she needs general help and doesn't understand what that has indicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Type set to A

**This means that you've told the FTP server you will be transferring by ASCII.**

**You almost never actually want to do ASCII, it is better to make a habit of using Binary for all transfers.**  (ASCII breaks the chain of custody, ASCII transfers can modify file contents such as changing New line characters and not sending correct Unicode characters and are completely unsuited to binary file contents, while the speed benefits are trivial.)

You want to make sure your FTP script uses commands separately it looks like you put a CD along with an MGet here...?

Example FTP Script:

```
user USERNAME PASSWORD
binary
lcd C:\Local\File\System\Folder
cd /root/dir_here/subdir_here
mget sample*.txt
quit
```

This would be in a script file which would be specified in the FTP command when you call it from the command line or from a script.

eg:

```
ftp -n -i -v "-s:C:\Local\Path\To\FTP\Script.txt" SERVER_IP
```

Comment: ohhh that's why I always get an error. thanks! I will try the example you've given :) may I ask what the -n -i and -v does? I'm sorry, I'm not that familiar with cmd syntax since it's new to me

Comment: -n            No auto-login. (Credentials are in file, it logs the FTP in)

   -i            No interactive prompts during ftp. (Suppress prompts because you're running a script)

   -v            Hide remote server responses.(Suppress prompts because you're running a script)

Comment: Oh, thank you for your time and effort to explain! Such a big help :)

Comment: Glad to help, mark this as the answer when you have a chance. :)

Comment: I know this might be a stupid thing to ask but is there ay way I can reach you? an email for example? :) I have bits of questions regarding the script I am creating and so far, you're the only one who's so kind and approachable to help me. thank you! if ever you don't want me to ask you through email, that will be fine also, I will understand :) God Bless!

Comment: you can email me on Work@Personick.com